# My db app stops working

Tags: android, android-database

I wrote some code. It does not give errors, but it simply does not work.

When I try to debug it, it says: Unfortunately your app has stopped.
Kindly help me, I am new to developing

The DataBase Helper Class is

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME= "permitManager",
TABLE_CONTACTS ="contacts",
KEY_ID = "id",
KEY_CAR="car",
KEY_STATUS="status",
KEY_IMAGEURI="imageUri";
public DatabaseHandler(Context context){
 super(context, DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
   }
  @Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
      db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS +""+ KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY," + KEY_CAR + "TEXT," + KEY_STATUS + "TEXT," + KEY_IMAGEURI + "TEXT,");
  }
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db,int oldVersion,int newVersion){
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS"+ TABLE_CONTACTS);
    onCreate(db);
}
public void createContact(Contact contact){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_CAR,contact.getCar());
    values.put(KEY_STATUS,contact.getStatus());
    values.put(KEY_IMAGEURI, contact.getimageURI().toString());
    db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS,null,values);
    db.close();
}

public Contact getContact(int id){
    SQLiteDatabase db =getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor =db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[]{KEY_ID,KEY_CAR,KEY_STATUS,KEY_IMAGEURI},KEY_ID + "=?" , new String[]{String.valueOf(id)},null,null,null);
    if(cursor!=null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    Contact contact = new Contact(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(2), Uri.parse(cursor.getString(3)));

    db.close();
    cursor.close();
        return contact;
    }
 public void  deleteContact(Contact contact){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase() ;
    db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS,KEY_ID+"=?",new String[]{String.valueOf(contact.getid())});
    db.close();
}

public int getContactCount(){
    SQLiteDatabase db= getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor =db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM" + TABLE_CONTACTS,null);
    int count = cursor.getCount();
    db.close();
    cursor.close();
    return count;
}
public int updateContact(Contact contact){
    SQLiteDatabase db= getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues values =  new ContentValues();

    values.put(KEY_CAR,contact.getCar());
    values.put(KEY_STATUS,contact.getStatus());
    values.put(KEY_IMAGEURI, contact.getimageURI().toString());
    db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS,null,values);
return db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS,values,KEY_ID +"=?",new String[]{String.valueOf(contact.getid())});
}
public List<Contact> getAllContacts(){
    List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor =db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM"+ TABLE_CONTACTS,null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            Contact contact = new Contact(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(2),Uri.parse(cursor.getString(3)));
            contacts.add(contact);
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
   }
    return contacts;
}
}
```

The main Activity Class is

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


 EditText carTxt, statusTxt;
 ImageView contactImageImgView;
 List<Contact> Contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();
 ListView contactListView;
 Uri imageUri=null;
 DatabaseHandler dbHandler;



 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     carTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtCar);
     statusTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtStatus);
     contactListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
     contactImageImgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgViewContactImage);
     dbHandler = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());


     TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabHost);


     tabHost.setup();
     TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Creator");
     tabSpec.setContent(R.id.Creator);
     tabSpec.setIndicator("Creator");
     tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

     tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("List");
     tabSpec.setContent(R.id.List);
     tabSpec.setIndicator("List");
     tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);


     final Button addBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);


     addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             Contact contact = new Contact(dbHandler.getContactCount(),String.valueOf(carTxt.getText()),String.valueOf(statusTxt.getText()),imageUri);
             dbHandler.createContact(contact);
             Contacts.add(contact);
             populateList();
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), carTxt.getText().toString() + " has been add to list", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
     });
     carTxt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
         @Override
         public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

         }

         @Override
         public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
             addBtn.setEnabled(!carTxt.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty());

         }

         @Override
         public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

         }
     });

     contactImageImgView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             Intent intent = new Intent();
             intent.setType("image/*");
             intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
             startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Contact Image"), 1);

         }
     });



      List<Contact> addableContacts = dbHandler.getAllContacts();
        int contactcount = dbHandler.getContactCount();
     for(int i =0;i< contactcount;i++) {
         Contacts.add(addableContacts.get(1));
     }
     if(!addableContacts.isEmpty())
         populateList();
 }

 public void onActivityResult(int reqcode, int rescode, Intent data){
     if(rescode == RESULT_OK){
         if(reqcode == 1){
             imageUri = data.getData();
             contactImageImgView.setImageURI(data.getData());
         }
     }
 }


 private void populateList() {
     ArrayAdapter<Contact> adapter = new ContactListAdapter();
     contactListView.setAdapter(adapter);
 }


 private class ContactListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Contact> {
     public ContactListAdapter() {
         super(MainActivity.this, R.layout.listview_item, Contacts);
     }

     @Override
     public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
         if (view == null)
             view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false);
         Contact currentContact = Contacts.get(position);

         TextView car = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contactname);
         car.setText(currentContact.getCar());
         TextView status = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.status);
         status.setText(currentContact.getStatus());
         ImageView img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img);
         img.setImageURI(currentContact.getimageURI());
         return view;
     }

 }
}
```

logcat is

```
08-27 05:17:06.704  13110-13110/com.newthinktank.helloworld E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
08-27 05:17:06.759  13110-13110/com.newthinktank.helloworld I/System.out﹕ Sending WAIT chunk
08-27 05:17:06.759  13110-13110/com.newthinktank.helloworld W/ActivityThread﹕ Application com.newthinktank.helloworld is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
08-27 05:17:06.766  13110-13117/com.newthinktank.helloworld I/dalvikvm﹕ Debugger is active
08-27 05:17:06.962  13110-13110/com.newthinktank.helloworld I/System.out﹕ Debugger has connected
08-27 05:17:06.962  13110-13110/com.newthinktank.helloworld I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
08-27 05:17:07.157  13110-13110/com.newthinktank.helloworld I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
08-27 05:17:07.360  13110-13110/com.newthinktank.helloworld I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
08-27 05:17:07.563  13110-13110/com.newthinktank.helloworld I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
08-27 05:17:07.759  13110-13110/com.newthinktank.helloworld I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
08-27 05:17:07.962  13110-13110/com.newthinktank.helloworld I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
08-27 05:17:08.165  13110-13110/com.newthinktank.helloworld I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
08-27 05:17:08.368  13110-13110/com.newthinktank.helloworld I/System.out﹕ debugger has settled (1343)
08-27 05:17:08.766  13110-13110/com.newthinktank.helloworld W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
08-27 05:17:08.766  13110-13110/com.newthinktank.helloworld I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
08-27 05:17:08.774  13110-13110/com.newthinktank.helloworld W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve interface method 14046: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
08-27 05:17:08.774  13110-13110/com.newthinktank.helloworld D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
08-27 05:17:08.774  13110-13110/com.newthinktank.helloworld I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
08-27 05:17:08.774  13110-13110/com.newthinktank.helloworld W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve interface method 14050: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
08-27 05:17:08.774  13110-13110/com.newthinktank.helloworld D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
08-27 05:17:10.149  13110-13110/com.newthinktank.helloworld I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onRtlPropertiesChanged, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.onRtlPropertiesChanged
08-27 05:17:10.149  13110-13110/com.newthinktank.helloworld W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 13947: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onRtlPropertiesChanged (I)V
08-27 05:17:10.149  13110-13110/com.newthinktank.helloworld D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0007
08-27 05:17:10.173  13110-13110/com.newthinktank.helloworld I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
08-27 05:17:10.173  13110-13110/com.newthinktank.helloworld W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 403: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
08-27 05:17:10.173  13110-13110/com.newthinktank.helloworld D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
08-27 05:17:10.173  13110-13110/com.newthinktank.helloworld I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
08-27 05:17:10.173  13110-13110/com.newthinktank.helloworld W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 425: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
08-27 05:17:10.173  13110-13110/com.newthinktank.helloworld D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
08-27 05:17:10.563  13110-13110/com.newthinktank.helloworld I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable
08-27 05:17:10.563  13110-13110/com.newthinktank.helloworld W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 366: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
08-27 05:17:10.563  13110-13110/com.newthinktank.helloworld D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
08-27 05:17:10.563  13110-13110/com.newthinktank.helloworld I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawableForDensity
08-27 05:17:10.563  13110-13110/com.newthinktank.helloworld W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 368: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
08-27 05:17:10.563  13110-13110/com.newthinktank.helloworld D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
08-27 05:17:11.485  13110-13110/com.newthinktank.helloworld E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) near "FROMcontacts": syntax error
08-27 05:17:11.493  13110-13110/com.newthinktank.helloworld D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
08-27 05:17:11.493  13110-13110/com.newthinktank.helloworld W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40b762a0)
08-27 05:17:11.665  13110-13110/com.newthinktank.helloworld E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity  ComponentInfo{com.newthinktank.helloworld/com.newthinktank.helloworld.MainActivi ty}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "FROMcontacts": syntax error  (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROMcontacts
at  android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:
at  android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2174)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:141)
at  android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1267)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5059)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "FROMcontacts": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROMcontacts
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
at              android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnecti     on.java:882)
at         android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
at     android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>    (SQLiteProgram.java:58)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>    (SQLiteQuery.java:37)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1253)
at com.newthinktank.helloworld.DatabaseHandler.getAllContacts(DatabaseHandler.java:83)
at com.newthinktank.helloworld.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:106)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5058)
at     android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2174)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:141)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1267)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5059)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at            com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-27 05:17:12.266  13110-13110/com.newthinktank.helloworld I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 13110 SIG: 9
```

Comment: You need to post your logcat that shows the error.

Comment: My only question is why are you using an database within android?

Answer (score 2):

This is your error (missing spaces, brackets + extra comma at the end):

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS +""+ KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY," + KEY_CAR + "TEXT," + KEY_STATUS + "TEXT," + KEY_IMAGEURI + "TEXT,");
```

and (twice!!)

```
Cursor cursor =db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM" + TABLE_CONTACTS,null);
```

and

```
 db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS"+ TABLE_CONTACTS);
```

---

This is the fix:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS +" ("+ KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY, " + KEY_CAR + " TEXT, " + KEY_STATUS + " TEXT, " + KEY_IMAGEURI + " TEXT)");
```

and (twice!!)

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS, null);
```

and

```
 db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ TABLE_CONTACTS);
```

Comment: why do people insist on writing SQL themselves, when a/ there are plenty of library to do that and b/ there are tons of identical errors on SO, all about a missing whatever in the query.

Comment: @njzk2 Me, because I don't like the use of **unnecessary** 3rd party libs. And because I like SQL. Then, I fully agree with you that many users do the same errors again and again.

Comment: The last time I had to use SQL in android, I found it was faster and less error prone to write a minimal library to handle the automatic creation of the tables, with wrappers around the queries to limit the amount of SQL to be written outside of that library. (all that to say that the library does not have to be 3rd party, and that isolating that kind of work - in a library, in a sense - is not unnecessary)

Comment: @njzk2 Oh, well, in `that` sense. A Class module. Which is what I do as well. But that module uses SQL constructs, doesn't it?

Comment: yes, it does. (but usually those are generated - either from configuration or introspection - and the generator can be unit tested individually)

Comment: SIR THIS IS NOT THE PROBLEM THIS IS FINE 
PROBLEM IS IN THE LINE OF " SELECT * FROM " I SEE IT IN LOGCAT
SORRY FOR MY BAD ENGLISH

Comment: Ok, I overlooked you had the same problem in your query. I edited my answer.